# SSO using liferay

Tags: liferay, liferay-6, ntlm, cas, ntlmv2

I want to acheive SSO from liferay configured to LDAP. I have configured my liferay to AD and it is authenticating and working fine. I want to add SSO feature to my application. Once logged into windows ldap. Using my ldap login/password. My application should not ask for the user name password. Is there a way to acheive such a kind of SSO using liferay.

Any help is appreciated.

thanks
Lokesh

Answer (score 0):

Please visit this [link](http://www.liferay.com/community/wiki/-/wiki/Main/OpenSSO%20Integration). Open SSO configuration is there in Liferay which you can use for SSO requirement.

-- 
Jaynil